# Can't get Custom BCS Connector with filters to work

Tags: visual-studio, bcs, wcf

I am trying to create a BCS connector in Visual Studio that connects to a WCF service. 
I first used an parameterless GetAccounts method as the source for the ReadList method, and the wanted to add filters (paging).

But as soon as i add a FilterDescriptor and an accompanying In parameter, I cannot create an external list anymore that uses the external content type, because the ReadList method has more TypeDescriptors than the ReadItem method (which are added because of the In limit and page parameters). What am I doing wrong?

My sample project can be found [here](http://www.dcubed.nl/BdcModelProject2.zip)

Comment: Does the read list method work in the BDC web parts like business data list?